# What is bindServiceAsUser() method in Android?

Tags: android, android-context, bindservice

I cannot understand what is the `bindServiceAsUser()` method used for. Can anyone please kindly explain about it ? Googling seems doesn't help much.

```
    public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection connection, int flags) {
    return mContext.bindServiceAsUser(intent, connection, flags, UserHandle.OWNER);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never felt the need to use `bindServiceAsUser()`, but here's what the Android documentation has to say about it:

> Same as bindService(android.content.Intent,android.content.ServiceConnection,int), but with an explicit userHandle argument for use by system server and other multi-user aware code.

The multi-user support was added in Android 4.2 (API: 17), read about it [HERE](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers). In my understanding it'll be mostly used by device manufacturers, releasing special devices for the Enterprise world for example. The best doc for multi-users I've found is [THIS](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multiuser-apps.html) one, along with all referenced links there.

Comment: When should individual devs use `bindServiceAsUser()`?

Answer (score 1):

As Vesko said, in most android devices multi user is disabled. Some device manufacturers enable it. Foe example you have to bind a service with AIDl and disable a feature for a user in your privileged app. Here you need to know bind service as which user. We can invoke `bindServiceAsUser` using reflection.

```
  UserManager um = (UserManager) getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE);
        UserHandle owner = null;
                    owner = um.getUserForSerialNumber(0L);
                  try {
            MethodUtils.invokeMethod(getApplicationContext(), "bindServiceAsUser", new Object[]{i, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE, owner});
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```